# TextInputLayout floating label gravity

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having some troubles with the TextInputLayout from the design support library on Android 4.1.

So, I have a simple layout with two TextInputLayout. I would like to have the hint on right because the text is in arabic.

I managed to put the hint on the right by using gravity="right". But I'm noticing a strange behaviour of the floating label when the EditText is focused.

The Floating label still stick to the left of the screen.

How can I have both the hint and the floating label on right ?

Here is my layout :

```
<LinearLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.aurelien.testblablabla.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:hint="جزر"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:hint="تفاحة"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the result:

[image]

I'm using com.android.support:design:23.1.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you **can't** customize the label position `TextInputLayout`. Either way if you using `TranslationY` even this is not the suitable solution for changing the floating label postion because it will translate any view.

Comment: Should I simply disable the floating label for android 4.1 and below ? I'm not having this problem on android 4.2 and higher. May be a custom TextInputLayout class could solve the problem ?

Comment: in android version from 4.2 and higher you can change position of floating label im i correctly undestand what you told ?

Comment: Sorry my previous message wasn't clear. Thanks to RTL support, I'm not having this issue on 4.2 and higher.  So should I simply give up for lower version ? :) If I have to give up I will !

Comment: Can you enter with chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107644/textinputlayout-floating-label-gravity

Comment: hmm ok , again i think you cant customize your floating label in you must to give up from it.

Comment: have you got any way for it because I'm having  the same problem now.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

use android:gravity="right" on the EditText

I did it like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/ti_cvv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/guideline_center"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ti_credit_card_number"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_cvv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:hint="@string/cvv"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            tools:text="XXXX"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use   layout Direction it solve your problem

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/img_edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:helperText="URL"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr"
        app:helperTextEnabled="true">
```

Comment: Question is like three years old. Are you sure this is working for the Android version that is mentioned?